# python and (android) adb shell

Tags: android, python, shell, cmd, adb

i would like to simulate touch on my anroid phone through a python code on my computer using the "adb shell tap x y" function (or any other way you may know). I have tried using

```
from subprocess import call
call(["adb", "kill-server"])
call(["adb", "shell"])
call(["input", "tap" , "1400" , "800"]) //example of x and y
```

but it just reaches the "shell" call and gets stuck.
(I know the tap function works because it works on the ordinary cmd window)

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2013/06/emulating-touchscreen-interaction-with.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["adb", "shell", "input", "tap" , "1400" , "800"])
```

In your original script:

1. You start a remote shell on your Android device (`adb shell`)
2. After you quit the remote shell typing `exit`, you issue a command on your host computer shell (`input tap 1400 800`).

Instead you should use adb to redirect a command to the Android device's remote shell. To do that, just append the command after `adb shell`, for example `adb shell input tap 1400 800`. Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/shell.html#shellcommands).

I also removed the `adb kill-process` line because there is no `kill-process` adb command.

Comment: No problem :-)  If the answer helped you, consider upvoting and accepting it, so to help other people in the future.